# phpStorm как почистить содержимое href на проекте?

Tags: phpstorm

Подскажите, как на всем проекте автоматически очистить (или заменить на href="#") у всех ссылок пути? Разумеется что у каждой ссылки прописан свой путь и банальный Ctrl + Shift + R тут не подойдет.

Comment: Попробуйте замену по регулярному выражению https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html

Comment: Почему не подойдет, там очень мощная логика и предварительный просмотр. Это как раз то.

Comment: С регулярками было бы суппер, может кто-то ещё подскажет как зарезать всё что между " " ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать [Structural Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.2/structural-search-and-replace.html). Вроде такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Occurrences count для `$text$` - 0,1. Для `$value$` - 1,1. Для `$attribute$` - 0,unlimited